# Removing ViewExpiredException messages in the log in Seam

Tags: seam, jsf-1.2

I was wondering if anyone has found a way to "deal" with the ViewExpiredException messages that are logged by Seam applications. We have dealt with the expection itself, everything redirects correctly and we are happy with how we are handling that side of things, but the error messages themselves are very annoying, and pollute the logs. Our clients user tend to try and just keep the application open all the time, which lends to a lot of these.

We have a Seam application operating on Glassfish 2.1.

I have found this link [here](http://javalabor.blogspot.co.nz/2011/09/jsf-2-global-exception-handling.html) which declares a custom exception handler to manage all faces exceptions, but this seems very intrusive, and I am nowhere near confident that I would not inadvertently hide something important.

Has any one else been able to find a nice way to remove these?